# JSF rich calender validation issue

Tags: validation, jsf, calendar

I have JSF1.2 rich calendar which provides Converter message when it fails the format or invalid format. But user is not correcting that and submitting the form.

Since it's not a valid format. Date Object does not hold the invalid date thus I am not able to validate the Date at Java level as i get null or if it had a valid previous value .

your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: It is not clear which problem exactly you're trying to solve. It is at least not possible to submit a form if conversion/validation has failed.

Comment: Once validation error is displayed user is not correcting it . submitting the form. [ we have save button it tries to save the form ] is not doing the validation again.

Comment: So the save button does actually not submit/process the calendar? Is it an ajax button?

Comment: Its a a4j:commandLink, with data="#{bean.updated}".

Comment: To eliminate ambiguity, post a [MCVE] so that anyone else in the world can see and reproduce your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: <a4j:commandLink  value='Save &amp; Refresh'
     rendered='#{showSaveRefresh}'
     data="#{bean.updated}" 
     oncomplete="return evalSaveRefresh(data);"/>